# OGR Info - Check for spatial index?

Tags: gdal, ogr

If we want to get information about a vector layer (shapefile for example) we could use ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo -so myshapefile.shp mylayer
```

This returns a lot of pertinent information about the shapefile.  Is it possible to return whether or not a spatial index exists?  If so, can we access info about the spatial index?

Note: I realize it is trivial to open the folder containing the shapefile and looking for a .sbn or .sbx and so the question is specific to ogrinfo.

Comment: I have the same question, with the emphasis on GeoPackage.

Answer (score 7):

With [GDAL 2.2.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.2.0-News), one of the changes to the GPKG driver is:

- add HasSpatialIndex(tblname,geomcolname) SQL function

For example:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT HasSpatialIndex('some_layer', 'geom')" some-file.gpkg
```

Shows:

```
INFO: Open of `some-file.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
HasSpatialIndex: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  HasSpatialIndex (Integer) = 1
```

Or better, select from [`gpkg_geometry_columns`](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#_gpkg_geometry_columns) to show info for all geometry columns in the file:

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT table_name, column_name, HasSpatialIndex(table_name, column_name) FROM gpkg_geometry_columns" some-file.gpkg
```

Answer (score 5):

As an answer to the comment by @Richard Law, the name of the virtual rtree table that contains the spatial index in GeoPackage is always named according to template 
`rtree_[table_name]_[geometry_column_name]`

Therefore you can make a SQL query that checks the existence of the rtree table.

For example you can check if table "table1" has a spatial index with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo -sql "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name like 'rtree_table1_%') as has_spatial_index" mygeopackage.gpkg


INFO: Open of `mygeopackage.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
has_spatial_index: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  has_spatial_index (Integer) = 1
```

In this case the spatial indes does exist. Otherwise the would have been "0".

In GeoPackage a table can have only one geometry field and therefore it is enough to make a check by just "rtree" and name of the table without knowing the name of the geometry field as `rtree_table1_%`.

Comment: Good answer. I'm just disappointed that there is no abstraction for this across different vector formats.

Comment: By looking at the list of supported OGR formats https://gdal.org/ogr_formats.html quite few formats support spatial index at all. Most database formats support spatial indexes transparently and it is rather hard to find for example from Oracle if table has a spatial index or not.I guess that such abstaction will not land into GDAL soon.

Answer (score 1):

Ogr does not use the ESRI spatial Index files .sbn, sbx. It creates a .qix file which may contain a spatial index and/or an attribute index. You can build the .qix via ogrinfo. 
[Ogr shapefile driver](http://gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html)

I also found a GDAL ticket mentioning .sbn file is now readable. Not sure what this means.

[ticket #4719](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4719)

Comment: "Starting with OGR 1.10, [the ESRI Shapefile driver] can also use the ESRI spatial index files (.sbn / .sbx)" http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_shapefile.html

Comment: @MikeToews Looks like I had better upgrade.  Thanks!

Comment: @JayLaura 1.10 is not released yet, but I'm certain the developers would love to have it tested

Comment: GDAL/OGR 1.10.0 came out last week:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/1.10.0-News