# Determining which QGIS layer has spatial index

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, spatial-index

I would like to loop over all layers within a QGIS project and determine which layer don't have a spatial index and cause QGIS to slow down.

I tried the method `hasSpatialIndex()` but this always returns `SpatialIndexUnknown` even if it's for example a shapefile with qix file present in the same folder (created from QGIS itself).

```py
source = iface.activeLayer()

if source.hasSpatialIndex() == QgsFeatureSource.SpatialIndexNotPresent:
    print("not present")
elif source.hasSpatialIndex() == QgsFeatureSource.SpatialIndexUnknown:
    print("unknown")
elif source.hasSpatialIndex() == QgsFeatureSource.SpatialIndexPresent:
    print ("present")
else:
    print ("something else")
```

I guess it's a bug that QGIS does not recognize the qix files in the same folder where the shapefiles are stored?

Is there really no PyQGIS-method to check layers if they are indexed? I am pretty sure that QGIS itselfs checks the existence of a spatial index because it uses the spatial index automatically if it exists.

Comment: I think that hasSpatialIndex should work with GeoPackage layers.

Comment: @user30184: yes I think geopackage and spatialite works better, even with ogr but I am looking for a more generic solution to query shapefiles, postgis layers and so on

Comment: Your question is related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53670/ogr-info-check-for-spatial-index. SpatiaLite and GeoPackage are special with spatial index because index does not just work but index must be requested in a subquery.

Comment: For shp, except checking the extension sbn/sbx or qix exist, not sure how to do it. `hasSpatialIndex` work well only for index in spatial databases (PostGIS,  Gpkg and Spatialite)

Answer (score 3):

QGIS is able to check if the layer has spatial index or not for several providers, including shapefiles.

I've create a new project with two shapefiles. For one, I've created a spatial index. Then I used the GUI and PyQGIS to check if the index is correctly detected and reported.

[image: test project]

#### GUI: Check layer properties

Layer properties panel will tell if the layer has spatial index or not.

For this shapefile layer, since a spatial index exists, the option "Create Spatial Index" is disabled (and a label Spatial Index Exists is used).

[image: Layer properties with Create Spatial Index disabled]

For another layer, the spatial index does not exist.

[image: Layer properties with Create Spatial Index enabled]

#### PyQGIS

If the GUI is showing the correct information, PyQGIS will do the same.
You can test with this tiny script.

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if (layer.dataProvider().hasSpatialIndex() == 1):
        print( f'The {layer.name()} has no spatial index' )
    if (layer.dataProvider().hasSpatialIndex() == 2):
        print( f'The {layer.name()} has a spatial index' )
```

Running this is writing the following output:

```
The madeira_com_indice has a spatial index
The madeira_sem_indice has no spatial index
```